# Integrating Django Admin with Firebase

Tags: python, django, firebase

I'm working on a mobile application where the backend is done by Dango but all the authentication and real-time database are in firebase
is there any way to integrate a Django admin with firebase instead of using firebase admin?

if not, can firebase admin be used with python to create an admin role and has the same permissions which Django gives to admin? and how to introduce the created role if possible to Django?

Answer (score 0):

One of the many beauties of Django is the admin interface, which I use all the time. Django relies on certain types of databases - namely relational databases. With NoSQL databases, you lose Django admin. If you want to Firebase with Python, I would recommend Flask.